# Swift 3 : Using Side Bar Menu

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm gonna try to use `KYDrawerController` or `SWRevealViewController` for side bar menu. But there is a problem, everyone gives an example with the same viewcontroller. I want to change the viewcontroller when I press the cell on the tableView and keep the side bar menu. This is the first time I'm using side bar menu. I guess that's why I don't get the main idea and I can't do this. If you give me an idea or sample about it I'll appreciate for it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use alternative [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library written in Swift 3. It's very flexible and well-supported library that is well suited for your needs. Also, there is a [Sample](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu/tree/master/Sample) with different controllers including TabBar.
Hope, it'll be useful for you.

[image: gif]

Comment: Can we show side menu on top of view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SWRevealViewController for implementing the side menu.

```
 FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
 newFrontController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
 [revealController pushFrontViewController:newFrontController animated:YES];
```

Where `revealController` is the instance of SWRevealViewController that you are using initially to implement your side menu.
For more details download `SWRevealViewController`'s example project from [gitHub](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and refer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll check it and let you know when I did it. I hope it works for me.

Comment: Ok thanks, please confirm whether it works or specify if you encounter any problems.